# Clone divs with option of drop down menu Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, forms, html-select

I have 1 select box which has numbers as options. I have 3 input text boxes inside a div.

When the user selects a number in the select box, I would like to duplicate that div depending on the number of the select box...

Important part is that, the ID and the name of each text box has to increment, so something like this:

```
text_box_first_1, text_box_second_2, text_box_thrid_3
text_box_first_2, text_box_second_2, text_box_thrid_2
```

EDIT:
Sorry, forgot to post what I got:

```
      <script>
    function clone(){
        var $newdiv = $('.initial_clone_div:first').clone();
        $('#add_clones_here').append($newdiv);
    }

    $('#num_periods').change(function () {
        for(var counter = 0; counter < $(this).val()-1; counter++) {
            $('.period_title').html('Period ' +(counter+1));
            clone();
        }
    });


</script>

 <!-- Period scores -->
    <div class="form-group initial_clone_div">
        <h3 class="period_title" id="period_title_1">Period 1</h3>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="control-label" for="num_periods">{{{ Lang::get('admin/teams/terms.blue_team') }}}</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="blue_team_period_1" id="blue_team_period_1" />    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="control-label" for="num_periods">{{{ Lang::get('admin/teams/terms.grey_team') }}}</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="grey_team_period_1" id="grey_team_period_1" />    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label class="control-label" for="num_periods">{{{ Lang::get('admin/teams/terms.black_team') }}}</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="black_team_period_1" id="black_team_period_1" />  
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./ Period scores -->   

    <div id="add_clones_here">

    </div>
```

I don't know how to modify the id's and name's of the text boxes.
I also got a problem showing the right Period number (the h3 tag)

EDIT: SOLUTION:

```
    function clearClones(){
        $('.initial_clone_div').each(function (i) {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }

    $('#num_periods').change(function () {
        $div =  $('.initial_clone_div:first');
        clearClones();
        for (var j = 1; j <= $('#num_periods').val(); j++) {
            $div.clone()
                .appendTo('#outer_div')
                .find('input')
                .each(function (k, v) {
                    if(k+1 == 1)
                        var team = "blue";
                    else if(k+1 == 2)
                        var team = "grey";
                    else if(k+1 == 3)
                        var team = "black";

                var theId = team+ 'team_period_' + (j);
                $(v).attr('id', theId);
                $(v).attr('placeholder', theId);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a place to come and request code to be written for you, but to troubleshoot the code you have written yourself. If you haven't made any attempts yet, I suggest you try and find another resource to get you started and then return here once you've hit a road block.

Comment: Oups sorry, I meant to post my code but forgot -.- I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fiddle ([LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/MxtLq/1/)) that should be easy to follow on how to do this.

**HTML**

```
<select id="select"></select>
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="theDiv">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Create dropdown
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    $('#select').append('<option value="' + i + '">Clone ' + i + ' Times</option>');
}

// Do main procedure
var inc=1;

$('#select').change(function () {
    inc++
    for (var j = 0; j <= $('#select').val(); j++) {
        $('#theDiv').clone()
            .appendTo('#outerDiv')
            .find('input')
            .each(function (k, v) {
            var theId = 'input_' +inc+ '_' + (j + 1) + '_' + (k + 1);
            $(v).attr('id', theId);
            $(v).attr('placeholder', theId);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove clones so that when a user choses 2, there is only 2 clones. If they choose 3, there is only 3...Right now it doesn't erase the other clones I believe...

Comment: Nvm, I found a way. I added the solution to my question. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) Get the `id` of the element that is going to be cloned.  Since you want to increment only the number, you have to split based on the `_`

```
var sp = $('.initial_clone_div:first').prop('id').split('_');
```

2) Convert the the last index of `sp` array to number and increment it.  Then again convert back to `string` dataType.

```
sp[3] = (+sp[3]+1).toString();
```

3) Now join and set the `newId` to the cloned element.

4) [.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] [, deepWithDataAndEvents ] )](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents)

```
var newId = sp.join('_');
var $newdiv = $('.initial_clone_div:first').clone(true, true).prop('id', newId);
```

Comment: @AraSivaneswaran Sure take your own time to learn it.  let me if you face any issue, if I am available I will let you know soon.

Comment: Ok, I tried it but it keeps trying to change the id of the div. But I want it to change the ID of the textbox inside the div...